# NLog - File Rotation - Sequence Issue

Tags: nlog

I am using Nlog for logs and rotating file on daily basis. Log files are read and processed further by another system to move to Splunk.

Here I am looking to find out what steps nlog takes to rotate file because it is failing my integration with other systems. It works fine with other log framework like log4net/logback. If that's case, I may need to switch to other framework.

Ideally steps should be - Approach 1

```
 1. Open file - abc.txt 
 2. add log line 1, log line 2.. log line n. 
 3. 12.00 AM - file rotation - Rename file abc.txt => 2020-05-13 abc.txt 
 4. create new file - abc.txt 5. add log line a1, log line a2.. log line an.
```

Another approach may be - Approach 2

```
 1. open file - abc.txt
 2. add log line 1, log line 2.. log line n.
 3. 12.00 AM - file rotation - create new file 2020-05-13 abc.txt
 4. move contents from abc.txt to new file 2020-05-13 abc.txt
 5. Update file offset/pointer to move to new location i.e. start of the file (as contents are removed from this file)
 6. add log line a1, log line a2.. log line an - at the begining location (offset/file pointer)
```

Can anybody please confirm which approach or sequence of steps are exactly performed by Nlog for file rotation.

[UPDATES] 
Below is how my config looks like-

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="logDir" value="C:\logs">
    <targets>
        <target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDir}\API_${machinename}.json"
        archiveFileName="${logDir}\{#}_API_${machinename}.json" archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" archiveEvery="Day">
            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffzzz}"/>
                <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
                <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}"/>
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logFile" />
    </rules>
 </nlog>
```

Comment: When making use of NLog FileTarget `archiveFileName`-option to move/rename active filename, then NLog will use "Approach 1". But if you have configured the `archiveFileName`-option so it will generate the same archived-file when rotating the second time, then NLog will instead copy the file-contents to the existing archived-file (And then truncate and also delete the active file if possible, for proper restart after rotate)

Comment: Maybe you can include the NLog.config showing the FileTarget-configuration you are using?

Comment: Hi Rolf, Thanks for response. Yes I am using archiveFileName option so that active file name always remains same while archive file names are different from active one. 1.Is there any way I can rotate daily and not have truncate at all? Truncate is causing issue in my case. 2. If I remove archiveFileName then is there any way to separate name of archive file from active file? Thanks.

Comment: In my case I understand that active file is never getting deleted and proper restart is never happening for rotation. Is there any way to force it to happen so that active file gets freshly created each time when rotation kicks in?

Comment: Not sure I understand "active file is never getting deleted", since NLog performs a rename of the active file to the new location specified by `archiveFileName`. So there is no file to delete when creating the new active file.

Comment: You should consider adding `encode="false"` to the exception-attribute: `<attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" encode="false" />`

Comment: Thank you for the `NLog.config` . If only single application is writing to the file, then there should not be any issue with "active file is never getting deleted". Could you enable the NLog InternalLogger https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging on Debug-Level and capture the output when the archive operation is "failing" ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I will add encode="false". So what I understand is - on every rotation, active file is new file and archived file is renamed file. - Approach 1. But I dont see it happening, I can see truncate statements in Splunk agent for active file while archived files are new ones. Not sure how to fix this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: InternalLogger is enabled and no error there. File rotation is happening. Issue is active file is truncated one and archived files are new ones. Instead I am looking for - active file (today's file) should be new one and archived files could be anything. I have multiple components in application and each generating their own logging file. All writing in same way as given config file. All gets rotated at midnight and issue with all log files.

Comment: You talk about "multiple components". Do each component has its own file? or do you have multiple file-targets writing to the same file? Was not asking whether any errors was written to InternalLogger, but whether you could capture the output on Debug-Level from InternalLogger when archive operation is misbehaving?

Comment: Yes, each component writing their own log file.

Comment: That is good, then NLog should not have issues with moving the active file. When you have captured the Debug-level output of the InternalLogger when the archive is misbehaving, then please tell. Maybe create an issue at Github, since StackOverflow is not good for troubleshooting sessions. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Comment: Here are some stats. I enabled internal log and here is finding. At 15:24:25.3012 archiving happens. In my log file I see 1st log statement at 15:24:25.146 and rest all statements are from and after 15:24:25.320. It clearly means that 1st log line written > then archiving happened > and then rest lines written. This is confusing. I just want to understand how it is working and want to know if there is a fix for this or not. Else I will move to other logging framework. Kindly help.

Comment: Again please create issue at NLog-project. Stackoverflow is not good for posting log-files and doing troubleshooting.

Comment: Raised at Github NLog - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3961